# Правильное подключение PDO

Tags: php, ооп, pdo

Есть подключение к БД:

```
class Db {

    public static function getConnection() {

        $paramsPath = ROOT . '/config/db_params.php';
        $params = include($paramsPath);

        $dsn = "mysql:host={$params['host']};dbname={$params['dbname']}";
        $db = new PDO($dsn, $params['user'], $params['password']);
        $db->exec("set names utf8");

        return $db;
    }

}
```

И в каждом классе, в каждом методе я делаю такое:

```
public static function getCategoriesList() {

    $db = Db::getConnection();

    $result = $db->query('SELECT id, name FROM category '
            . 'ORDER BY sort_order ASC');

   .........
}
```

Как избавитсья вот от этого говнокода?  `$db = Db::getConnection();`

Как можно в индексном файле вызывать подключение и не подключаться каждый раз в каждом методе? Как вариант создать класс подключения и в других классах стучаться в него через конструктор?

Comment: Правильно будет вот так `class DB extends \PDO {...}` если вы пишите/используете свою обертку над PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто сохраняйте соединение в статической переменной:

```
private static $db = null;
public static function getConnection() {
  if (!is_null(self::$db)) return self::$db;
  // ...
  self::$db = ...;
  return self::$db;
}
```

Однако, это способно доставить боль, как только возникнет необходимость во втором соединении.

В вашем случае(статические классы) примерно то же самое можно сделать и в клиентских классах:

```
class Advt {
  private static $db;
  public static function setDB(DB $db){self::$db = $db;}
  public static function getAdvtList($page = 1) {
    //...
    self::$db->query(...);
    //...
  }
}
Advt::setDB(DB::getConnection());
```

---

**Всё, что ниже - просто моё видение того, как примерно это должно быть.**

Лучше хранить соединение в экземпляре `DB`, и реализовав пару методов для запросов, работать с ним.
В классах, чьё существование без соединения с базой не имеет смысла, можно передать объект базы в конструктор и сохранить в `$this->db` скажем.

---

```
class Db {
  private $config;
  private $connection;
  public function __construct() {
    $paramsPath = ROOT . '/config/db_params.php';
    $this->config = include($paramsPath);
  }
  public function connect() {

        $dsn = "mysql:host={$this->config['host']};dbname={$this->config['dbname']}";
        $this->connection = new PDO($dsn, $this->config['user'], $this->config['password']);
        $this->connection->exec("set names utf8");
  }
  public function query($sql, $params) {
    if (!$this->connection) $this->connect();
    // prepare/execute
  }
  public function rows($sql, $params) {
    // query/fetch
  } // fetch rows
  public function row($sql, $params) {} // fetch one row
  public function col($sql, $params, $col = 0) {} // fetch column
  public function cell($sql, $params, $col = 0) {} // fetch scalar value
}
```

somecontroller.php

```
class A {
  protected $db;
  public function __construct(DB $db) {$this->db = $db;}
  public function getUser($id) {
    return $this->db->row('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id = ?', [$id]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А вот если не реализовывать к классе Db методы для запросов, а все делать в методах моделей. Эти методы будут статичными и $this-> там не прокатит. Вот на вашем примере в классе А передать обьект в конструктор и использовать его в static getUser($id).

Comment: И метод в классе бд connect тоже static

Comment: Использование чисто статических классов в основном бессмысленно.

Comment: В основной части моего ответа не было никакого `$this`

Comment: Согласен. А если метод connect класса Db будет статический и метод getUser класса А статический, то при выполнении запроса нужно не через $this-> делать?

Comment: Я извеняюсь, вас не затруднит заглянуть сюда https://bitbucket.org/rodnoy/advertisement/src/6c1b4c3ebed8c5227ab77f84534be3afc29f6f08/components/?at=master. В папке компоненты лежит класс БД с статическим методом подключения. В моделях есть класс Advt и в нем в каждом методе приходится делать  $db = Db::getConnection(); Как это можно избежать?

Comment: Всё так же, через `DB::getConnection()`, только соединение не будет создаваться заново, будет переиспользоваться старое

Comment: Написал в ответе. Но вам всё же стоит пересмотреть привычки использовать статические классы. Это программирование в глобальном контексте имеет мало общего с ООП.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше внимание. Думаю переписать все без статических классов и методов.