# Ошибка в Open Server

Tags: openserver

Здравствуйте! Есть ошибка:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
> 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
> (using password: NO)' in
> D:\WebServer\domains\mysite\components\Db.php:13 Stack trace: #0
> D:\WebServer\domains\mysite\components\Db.php(13):
> PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '') #1
> D:\WebServer\domains\mysite\models\News.php(44): Db::getConnection()
>
> ## 2 D:\WebServer\domains\mysite\controllers\NewsController.php(11): News::getNewsList() #3 [internal function]:
>
> NewsController->actionIndex() #4
> D:\WebServer\domains\mysite\components\Router.php(60):
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #5
> D:\WebServer\domains\mysite\index.php(36): Router->run() #6 {main}
> thrown in D:\WebServer\domains\mysite\components\Db.php on line 13

Код в файле `db.php`

```
class Db
{

        public static function getConnection()
        {
            $paramsPath = ROOT . '/config/db_params.php';
            $params = include($paramsPath);


            $dsn = "mysql:host={$params['host']};dbname={$params['dbname']}";
            $db = new PDO($dsn, $params['user'], $params['password']);

            return $db;
        }
}
```

код в файле `db_params.php`

```
return array(
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'dbname' => 'php_base',
            'user' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
);
```

Comment: Open Server тут ни при чем. На подобный вопрос уже давался ответ... Откуда все тянут этот class Db ? Из какого древнего фреймворка?
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625396/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-pdo

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я не разу не работал с PDO. Это чужой код, который просто должен работать. Не могли бы вы мне показать в файлах, конкретно, что именно нужно изменить, чтобы работало или выслать измененные фалы? А то, не совсем понятно... Спасибо!

Comment: Прежде всего, return array в файле db_params.php - это кусок некой функции, как я понимаю?

Comment: @labris нет, просто include и require могут возвращать то, что указано в return

Comment: Век живи - век учись :).

Comment: Сдается мне, что запятая после последнего элемента массива - лишняя.   'password' => '', );

Comment: Да, скорее всего вы правы. Запятая лишняя, но код всё равно не работает... Кто знает, помогите разобраться! Как сделать, чтобы работало...

Comment: Тогда надо отладкой заняться. По выдаваемой ошибке легко установить, что пользователю root запрещен доступ к базе данных. Значит, или переменные с ошибкой, или передаются с ошибкой, или оказываются вне видимости. Я бы действовал в следующей последовательности. 1) Проверить отдельным простейшим скриптом подключение к базе данных с указанными реквизитами. 2) Если все ОК, проверить работу кода без класса, в одном файле. 3) Если все ОК, значит переменные не видны или не работают в классе, и тут надо думать, почему.

Comment: Я открыл другой файл без классов вообще, с mysql. Причем и у user и password стоит mysql. И всё работает!  ... Разобраться с PDO я не могу, поскольку никогда до этого я с ним не встречался. Как то можно дать доступ к базе с именем root. Может здесь покопаться... Я просто не знаю как... У кого-то ещё есть какие-то мысли?

Comment: А как вы попадаете в phpmyadmin (или другую аналогичную приблуду) для вашей SQL?

Comment: А я захожу в не в phpadmin а в Mysql менеджер(Open server)